# Angular Dependency injection issues in angular libraries

Tags: angular

I have a angular app which has 3 libraries. One is a shared library and other two are libraries that are used as micro apps and I am using angular elements to render these two libraries. the shared library has services that are injecting angular classes like HttpClient, DecimalPipe etc.. and I am getting the static null injector error **(NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[CounterService -> CounterService -> CounterService -> CounterService -> DecimalPipe])** The shared library module has HttpClientModule, Common module, browser module in the imports section. If I create another service in the shared library module it works fine with DI.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedLibComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [SharedLibComponent],
  providers: [HttpClient, DecimalPipe]
})
export class SharedLibModule { }


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'platform'
})

export class CounterService {

  count: number = 0;

  constructor(private _decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
    console.log('inside constructor');
  }

  increment() {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count = this.count - 1;
  }
}
```

Here I am choosing providedIn as platform as it is micro apps. I only need one instance of the component across multiple micro apps which I am able to achieve by creating micro apps as libraries with a shell project.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyLibComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    MyAccountComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MyLibRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedLibModule
  ]
})
export class MyLibModule implements DoBootstrap {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    console.log('inside my lib module constructor');
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    console.log("PMB Module: Entered ngDoBootstrap...");
    const myElementExists = !!customElements.get("pmb-lib");
    if (!myElementExists) {
      const appElement = createCustomElement(MyLibComponent, {
        injector: this.injector
      });
      customElements.define("my-lib", appElement);
    }
    console.log("My lib Module: Completed ngDoBootstrap...");
  }
}

// If there is already a platform, reuse it, otherwise create a new one
(getPlatform() || platformBrowser()).bootstrapModule(MyLibModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Any idea or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to see that people out there actually use [my POC](https://github.com/flash-me/angular-micro-frontends). :)

**B2T**: *(Maybe this helps visualising the faulty reasoning)*

When you provide Services at **Platform** level, 
they inherit from the platform **Injector**.

When you bootstrap your Module, which imports e.g. **HttpClientModule** or **CommonModule** etc, 
then those Modules inherit from the platform **Injector**.

So whats the issue here? Right, for being able to inject stuff from HttpClientModule/CommonModule, the services must inherit the injector from that level and **not platform level**

We could create our custom "platform module", where the injector already knows HttpClientModule/CommonModule and use that "platform module" to "bootstrap" the other micro frontends. But still, even here your service would have to be 'root' or less and not 'platform'

**Example:**

```js
/**
 * This is a service which is provided by the "platform module"
 * so it can be used by all other modules. SINGLETON
 */
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
    private static count = 0;

    constructor(readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
        GlobalService.count++;

        // Ctor would crash anyway. But hey, insanity..
        if (!httpClient) {
            throw new Error('HTTPCLIENT COULD NOT BE INJECTED');
        }
    }

    printMessage() {
        console.log(`[${GlobalService.name}]: Count: ${GlobalService.count}`);
    }
}

/**
 * This is your "platform module", which provides services
 * that can be used by every other micro frontends.
 *
 * DO NOT IMPORT THIS MODULE
 *
 * the modules have access to everything provided by this module.
 * This is the grandparent of your parents grandparents.
 *
 * Services provided here are shared globally,
 * they will be singleton, and they access to stuff
 * like HttpClientModule. Think of it like "ApplicationModule"
 */
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
    providers: [GlobalService]
})
export class MfePlatformModule implements DoBootstrap {
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() @Inject(MfePlatformModule) parentModule: MfePlatformModule|null) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error(
                `You did it right? You imported MfePlatformModule...`);
        }
    }

    // This is needed, if there are no components to bootstrap
    ngDoBootstrap(): void { }
}

/**
 * This is an example module, that makes use of the
 * service which is provided at platform level
 * Everything inside this module can also inject.
 * CAUTION
 * IMPORTANT
 * ATTENTION
 * The modules NEED to have an id like here
 * Can be any string, as long as they are unique
 */
@NgModule({
    id: ExampleMfeModule.name
})
export class ExampleMfeModule {
    private static count = 0;

    constructor(readonly sharedService: GlobalService) {
        ExampleMfeModule.count++;
        console.log(`ExampleMfeModule #${ExampleMfeModule.count} successfully instantiated`);
        this.sharedService.printMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the platform module create that contains
 * the root module including the injector,
 * which is used as the parent for every other module
 */
export const getPlatformModule = (function () {
    // Closure holdung the singleton module ref
    let platformModule: NgModuleRef<MfePlatformModule>;
    return () => {
        return new Promise<NgModuleRef<MfePlatformModule>>(resolve => {
            if (platformModule) {
                resolve(platformModule);
            }
            platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(MfePlatformModule)
                .then(moduleRef => {
                    platformModule ||= moduleRef;
                    resolve(platformModule);
                });
        });
    };
})();

/**
 * "Bootstrap" your micro frontends using this factory
 * instead of platformBrowser. They will have access
 * to global services (incl. HttpClientModule).
 * 
 * CAUTION: This is not actually a real bootstrap, where the
 * ngDoBootstrap will be called. This is more like importing.
 * If you want to init stuff, do it in the constructor like above
 * 
 * @param ngModule The Micro Frontend NgModule you want to "bootstrap"
 */
export const bootstrapMfe = <T>(ngModule: Type<T>): Promise<NgModuleRef<T>> =>
    getPlatformModule()
        .then(pf =>
            (getModuleFactory(ngModule.name) as NgModuleFactory<T>).create(pf.injector))
        .catch((error: Error) => console.error(`Error trying to bootstrap mfe ${ngModule}\n${error?.message}`, error) as any);


// Lets bootstrap two modules and check if everything works...
bootstrapMfe(ExampleMfeModule)
    .then(one => console.log(`Boostrapped first mfe`, one.instance))
    .then(() => bootstrapMfe(ExampleMfeModule))
    .then(second => console.log(`Boostrapped second mfe`, second.instance))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**Console output in the browser:**

[image: Output of the code example]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With my current setup I am having trouble to get this going. I will try to create a git repo to share my current setup so you can provide suggestions. With my setup if I move this code to my shell project(not a library). I am having trouble with build issues if I export these out and have my library projects access these functions as these reside outside their own source.